# Dom element is not refreshing in 2nd time but is works in first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing an ajax call and replacing the response inside a div class. At the first ajax call the response is replaced inside the class properly but 2nd time I got the data from response but the response in not replacing the data inside the class.

I am trying the below way.

```
$(document).on('click', '#approveallusers', function(){
     var checked_ids = []
     $("#UserList").find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
            if($this.is(":checked") && $this.hasClass('selectbox')){
                checked_ids.push($this.attr("userid"));
            }
     });
    $.ajax({
        url : '/approve-website-users',
        method : 'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify({'checked_ids':checked_ids}),
        contentType : "application/json",
        success : function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'success') {
                alert(data.res)
                $('.users').replaceWith(data.res);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

here `data.res` is an html element and its rendering from the server side.
Thanks..

Comment: Does the top element of the `data.res` have the `users` class?

Comment: ohh no..what a silly mistake..I have spent a lot of time..thanks buddy..its working now..

Answer (score 1):

`.replaceWith` will replace the div including html tags so there won't be any class users.

see this for more info: 
http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function

maybe you need `.innerHTML` or `.html` 
check here: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString